# How do I copy only most recently created file off remote computer to a new location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, copy

I have been searching for hours and cannot find an answer for this. I have several remote computers, and I want to be able to put the path where the backups are being made in, and have a python program that will only grab the most recent backup (one is being made every hour, and I only need to pull the most recent, one time a day) and copy it to our server.

I have been able to get the `os` and `shutil` to work to copy files from my computer to another location on my computer, but when I put the location of the remote folder in, I get `FileNotFoundError`.

The network path is similar to this in my explorer window:

`\\10.180.22.211\Data\Job\DatabaseBakup`

I am putting the double `\`'s in as well. But it is still not working.

Comment: No [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), no exception stacktrace provided. We can't help with unknown problem

Comment: Wild guess; Try setting the network path to `r'\\10.180.22.211\Data\Job\DatabaseBakup'`—note the `r` prefix. Also note that the proper spelling of the word is "Backup" not "Bakup".

Comment: Haha yes I misspelled it on here, but I copy/pasted the actual direct link from my windows explorer after navigating to the correct folder, so I know everything was spelt correctly in my code.  But why does it need the r in front?

Comment: @martineau putting the r in front worked. THANKS a ton!

Comment: Glad to hear the problem is solved. The `r` prefix is explained in the [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) section of the documentation. It's called a **`stringprefix`**.